# Gulp Serve: render index.html for all paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browser-sync

I'm running a simple AngularJS app, and serving it using Gulp / Gulp Serve with Browsersync.

To make my Angular routes work, I need to render `/index.html` for all paths on the port.

How do I do this? My current code is:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['less'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./app"
    });

    gulp.watch("app/css/*.less", ['less']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("app/js/**/*.js").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use this middleware, the [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback), like so:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['less'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: {
          baseDir: "./app",
          middleware: [ history() ]
        }
    });
});
```

Works perfectly now!